# How to modify an inner property of a nested object in Javascript using a variable reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, I want to set an inner property of an object stored in a state.

Suppose the following:

```
const myIndex = 0;
const [myobject, setmyobject] = useState({ 
  a: {
    b: [ 
      {c: 1}, 
      {c: 2} 
    ] 
  }
})
```

I want to modify myobject, replacing `c` with 3 in the first object of the `b` array.

So I want to do this:

```
setmyobject({...myobject, a.b[myIndex].c: 3});
```

But it gives me an error, `: or , expected` in the first `[`.

Is this forbidden?

[image]

Comment: you can use the computed property names syntax: `{...myobject, [a.b[myIndex].c]: 3}`

Comment: @NickParsons I get `a is not defined`

Comment: oh, yeah, you need to prefix it with `myobject.a.b[myIndex].c`

Comment: @NickParsons I tried that, result is not what I expected haha, updated the image

Comment: oh, I see, I didn't read the question properly, sorry. I guess you could use `myobject.a.b[myIndex].c = 3`, but that would involve modifying the original object... not 100% if there's an easy way of doing what you're after without explicitly deep cloning the object, and then modifying the cloned object's properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be best practice: https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';
const updatedMyObject = update(myObject, {
    a: {b: {[myIndex]: {c: {$set: 3}}}}
});
setmyobject(updatedMyObject);
```

Comment: Thanks, ended using Immers' `produce()`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, doing an immutable update like that in an object literal is a bit verbose:

```
setmyobject({
  ...myobject,
  a: {
    ...myobject.a,
    b: myobject.a.b.map((val, idx) => 
      idx === myIndex
        ? { ...val, c: 3 }
        : val
    )
  }
});
```

Libraries like [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs/#set) have some functionality you might find useful like `_.set`, which lets you pass in a property path. Another approach could be to deep clone the object and mutate it, but the above pattern works ok if you don't want the burden of heavy libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why do you need to do it exactly in 1 string of code. Just copy object as you do it:
`const obj2 = {...obj1}`

and then set the property you want:

`obj2.a.b[myIndex].c = 3`